# 301 redirect non-www to www not always working

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've read through a ton of posts and pages trying to figure this out.  I have it mostly working.  I have a .htaccess file setup and I'm trying to redirect (301) any page in my site from non-www to www version.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It seems to work from the base url.  However, it doesn't redirect for sub pages.

This works:

example.com -> www.example.com

This does NOT work:

example.com/foo.html -> www.example.com/foo.html

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Hmm... Quite a puzzler I use an almost identical rewrite on my site and it works fine. You could try adding RewriteBase / but I don't think it should make a difference.

Comment: Very odd indeed...  you can try a live example here

http://freetypes.com/foo.html

If you remove the "foo.html" you'll see it begins to work.

Comment: Ah I think you must have another rule in your htaccess that is messing it up. For example if I go to [freetypes.com/bar.html](http://freetypes.com/bar.html) it will forward correctly to the www and a 404 page.

Comment: This code did work for me with a little modification. At line 3 I had to replace `^(.*)$` by `^(.*)/$` in order to avoid having two slashes `//` after the domain. (Using Django 1.5.4)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add a `\` to escape the dot in your domain (line 2).

As in:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.yourdomain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

...as seen here: http://www.hostingdiscussion.com/promotion-marketing/26083-301-redirect-non-www-www-vice-versa-good-search-engine-optimization-technique.html

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my rule that work in my prod environment:

```
# If domain name without "www", add them:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomainname\.(fr|com|net|org|eu) [NC]
# without www => force redirection:
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomainname.%1$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```