# Adding "www" with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, web, no-www

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [301 redirect non-www to www not always working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972000/301-redirect-non-www-to-www-not-always-working)

I have a web site and it is possible to access it with both "www" and without "www" (e.g. *www.example.com* and *example.com*). mod_rewrite is used to redirect to www.example.com if there is no "www" in URL.

But, if I go to *example.com/something.html*, it gets redirected to *www.example.com* (*something.html* gets truncated).

Currently, the rule I have is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule /.* http://www.example.com [R]
</VirtualHost>
```

What is the easiest way to make rewriting recursive and to make *example.com/something.html* redirect to *www.example.com/something.html*

Comment: It's hard to believe this has not been asked before..... (hint: search `mod_rewrite prepend www`)

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```